# lateinit property editTextName has not been initialized

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-intent, syntax-error

This is my code, I am building a tictactoe game but i dont know what is wrong with it. I have MainActivity which then goes to either this activity shown below or another but when I try to go here app just crashes out of sudden and doesn't want to cooperate. I don't know how it can be fixed though, but I somehow managed to read that something is troubling on line 21. if anybody could help me out, I'll be more than happy.

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_name_input.*

class NameInput : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var name1: EditText
    private var name2: EditText
    private lateinit var editTextName: EditText
    private lateinit var editTextName2: EditText

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_name_input)
        title = "Input Player names"

        var name1 = editTextName.text.toString()
        var name2 = editTextName2.text.toString()

        val extras = intent.extras

        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.StartButton)
        button.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }


        val intent = Intent(this, GameActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("NAME", name1)
        intent.putExtra("NAME2", name2)

        startActivity(intent)

    }

}
```

Here is what I get

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.tictactoe, PID: 14250
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tictactoe/com.example.tictactoe.NameInput}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property editTextName has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property editTextName has not been initialized
        at com.example.tictactoe.NameInput.onCreate(NameInput.kt:21)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

App just crashes and does nothing

all I want to do is to get string value from `editTexts`. inputted names and pass them to another activity with intent, but it doesn't want to cooperate.

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: When using Kotlin synthetic, you don't need to use `findViewById` method or declare View variable inside your class, just use them directly from the code. Try to remove all class variables then run again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lateinit` means "I'm not initialising these variables yet, but I promise to set a value on them before anything tries to read them". But you're not setting them before you read them (like with `findViewById`), that's why it's crashing.

Since you're using synthetics in the import (so you can directly reference views in the layout by their IDs, without having to use `findViewById`), maybe you're just trying to access them that way? If your `EditText`s have IDs of `editTextName` and `editTextName2` in the XML, don't declare variables with the same names in your activity. I'm guessing your synthetic ones just get hidden - either way, you're trying to read those variables you've declared that haven't been initialised yet

Also your code basically inflates a layout, reads the default values from some `EditText`s, then immediately starts a new `Activity` without the user ever seeing this one. I'm assuming you probably want to do that after clicking the button!

Answer (score 0):

add this lines before `var name1 = editTextName.text.toString()`

```
editTextName = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextName)
editTextName2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editTextName2)
```

Comment: now it has new error: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property nameTextView has not been initialized

Comment: @DavidKhvedelidze but you done't have `nameTextView `. can you show the code and error line?

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning values to that is why you are getting crashes. Do remove these lines -

```
 private lateinit var editTextName: EditText
 private lateinit var editTextName2: EditText
```

user the id's of textviews form activity_name_input.xml directly.